# Spring 2.4 – Inject value into static variables

Tags: java, spring-boot

I try to implement static variable with Value annotation on Spring 2.4 but it doesn't work but it was working on Spring 2.1.

```
@Component
public class GlobalValue {

    public static String DATABASE;

    @Value("${mongodb.db}")
    public void setDatabase(String db) {
        DATABASE = db;
    }

}
```

Then I want to call it as static constant:

```
GlobalValue.DATABASE => but it gives null
```

Any suggestion?

You can find example about it: https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-inject-a-value-into-static-variables/

Comment: That is the risk of using statics. There is no guarantee that when you call `GlobalValue.DATABASE` that the `setDatabase` method has been called already, it could be initialized after the other bean. Generally speaking you shouldn't be doing things like this but rather you proper configuration properties.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't use statics.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```java
@RestController
public class GlobalValue {

    @Value("${mongodb.db}")
    private String database;

    private static String DATABASE_STATIC;

    @Value("${mongodb.db}")
    public void setDatabase(String db){
        GlobalValue.DATABASE_STATIC = db;
    }
}
```

Reference https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field